# Intellisense is telling me that Element 'a' must not be nested inside Element 'a button'. But it isn't

Tags: .net, visual-studio, html, intellisense

I keep getting Green squiggly lines underneath my `a` elements (not all of them) and it's really irritating me, because it's telling me that I am doing something that I am not.

---

[image]

Why does it think I am nesting my `<a>`'s inside a `button`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the `'a button'` bit is a list of tags.  You can't have an `a` tag inside another `a` tag, which is what you do have here.

Comment: But I've seen this countless times, with people using it as a way of implementing a Hover-based drop down (CSS-only) menu. It's not going to cause any rendering issues, if I leave it as-is, is it?

Comment: @JTS-V - I've seen plenty of people go through red lights without injuries. It doesn't mean that it's the correct thing to do though, does it?